# BSF Opcode is not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assembly, x86

I am using Visual Studio 2010 professional, and I just checked in debug mode that BSF is not working I tried a lot of combinations, none of them worked!

```
__asm
{   
    mov ebx, 0ffffffh;
    bsf ecx, ebx;
};
```

the code above at least give me some results but I got 0 on ecx register (I'm using 64-bit win7 and application is 32-bit)

Here's what Intel says about BSF:

> Searches the source operand (second
>   operand) for the least significant set
>   bit (1 bit). If a least significant 1
>   bit is found, its bit index is stored
>   in the destination operand (first
>   operand). The source operand can be a
>   register or a memory location; the
>   destination operand is a register. The
>   bit index is an unsigned offset from
>   bit 0 of the source operand. If the
>   content of the source operand is 0,
>   the content of the destination operand
>   is undefined.

Anybody has any thoughts? Thank you all...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're getting `ecx` set to 0 because the least significant (leastmost?) 1-bit in the value `0xffffff` *is* bit 0. The binary number for that is `0000 .... 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`.

In other words, the result you're seeing is correct.

If you were to try it on `0xfc` for example (binary `1111 1100`), you should get 2. This is because the least significant bits are in the rightmost positions of the binary number:

```
Hex        F    C
Binary   1111 1100
Bit#     7654 3210
               ^
               |
               +-- rightmost (least significant) 1-bit
```

Comment: +1, partly for a correct answer (I believe), but mostly for inventing the word "leastmost"... ;-)

Comment: @MCA: yes, I did. You're complaining that it says the rightmost 1 bit in 0xffffff is bit 0. I'm not sure _why_ you're complaining since that is indeed the right value. If you'd like to tell me where you think I'm wrong in a less obtuse fashion, I'll be happy to re-examine the answer.

Comment: oh yes you're right :) guess I was too tired to see that! you should've said the result was correct :)

Answer (score 4):

Don't use inline asm, use compiler intrinsics: [`_BitScanForward`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfd9z0bb.aspx)